# Does every android phone has streetview application by default?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers, google-street-view

Does every android phone with 2.3 and above has streetview by default or one have to download the streetview and install it. The reason I am asking is that I am using streetview in my application and I use

```
private boolean isIntentAvailable(Intent intent) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = mapView.getContext().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

to see if streetview application is available in the device. The problem is that in one of mobile with android 4.1.1 streetview is available but still this method throws false for that. But it works in most of the devices that I have tested like in all Samsung , HTC and sony mobiles.

Comment: So what is the intent you are calling this with to test for streetview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all android devices have Google apps. It depends of the constructor

[EDIT :]
to check if an app is installed, you may use :

```
appInstalledOrNot("com.google.android.apps.maps")
```

using the method:

```
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try {
               pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
               app_installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
               app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed ;
}
```

I read somewhere that all version of Maps have Street View, but I really can not confirm this, I am not sure.

Comment: Ok thanks but its seems the method I have provided doesn't seems to work in one of the devices can you help me with this one.